# How to set default value for class attributes using java annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, hibernate-validator

I want to set default values if not specified by user. eg, for `Boolean private isValid` , if we don't specify any json value, then it should set `false` . I am using hibernate validator, `@NotNull, @NotBlank, @Size, @Range`...Is there any annotations to set default value for boolean, int, float, irrespective of data types. I tired hard, but did not come up with any solution. Still I am trying..Your help is highly appreciated ! Thank you

Comment: Why not use a `boolean` instead of `Boolean`...

Comment: Presumably he might need his Boolean to be null if he has a legacy schema that allows null on that column.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do fallow in your class definition:

```
public YourClass{
....
private Boolean isValid=false;
....
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it is not working :(

Comment: How do you initialize it ? Did you load it from database? Maybe you just have true in your database ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add default value with column

```
@Column(name="isValid",columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default '0'")
private Boolean isValid;
```

Comment: I get compilation error "create annotation Column", could you please mention the required jar. I am not using Hibernate ORM.

Comment: @sayan Get jar here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final

Comment: I tried, but it didnt work. I am not using Hibernate ORM for my code, that's why it didnt work, I guess. I am only using hibernate-validator jars for validation purpose, not hibernate orm. Is there anything to set default values using annotations ? Please help. thnx.

Comment: @sayan This is the only way to set default value using java JPA annotations. check edited answer and try again.